# Does the wattage of the drill have to do with wood working?

Tags: power-tools, tools, tool-selection

Currently, I am browsing a local store via mobile device app. It shows a bundle of tool, it states:

1. Bosch Go (screwdriver) + GBM 320
2. Bosch Go (screwdriver) + GBM 350

Will there be a difference between those two? considering woodworking also deals with some metal and concrete sometimes

Comment: Are you asking about screwdrivers or about drills?

Comment: Specific shopping queries are off-topic for this SE so expect your Question to be closed. But more generally, wattage can be important (even if the tool will be used exclusively for wood, and never metal or concrete). Wattage is an indication of power and a more powerful drill is capable of drilling wider, deeper holes than one that's less powerful.

Comment: Apologies about the shopping terminologies, I was asking about if there is a signigicant performance difference between a 320W and 350W Drill that is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Graphus mentioned in a comment, the wattage is indicative of how powerful the drill is and more powerful drills can drill bigger holes. Per the product pages for both of the drills you mentioned, the [GBM 320](http://www.bosch-professional.com/ng/en/drill-gbm-320-213949-06011a45k0.html) can drill 13mm holes in wood, while the [GBM 350](http://www.bosch-pt.com.my/my/en/drill-gbm-350-213949-06011a95l0.html) can drill 20mm holes. It gives similar specs for drilling in steel. How precise those specs are is unknown, but it gives you an indication of what you can expect from those two drills.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me to be more particular when choosing a tool